# C++ How to Split a User Input String Into Multiple Strings

Tags: c++, string, split, user-input

im trying to get a user input: "aa bb cc dd ee" etc. which is stored in a single string and put it in multiple strings string_1 "aa", string_2 "bb", string_3 "cc", string_4 "dd", string_5 "ee" etc.

```
string str;
cin >> str; //user input

//code to split the string

string str_1, str_2, str_3, str_4, str_5;
```

Comment: `cin >> str;` will receive the 1st word of your input only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/most-elegant-way-to-split-a-string

Comment: Have you tried `cin >> str_1 >> str_2 >> str_3 >> str_4 >> str_5;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, std::string)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) already does that *splitting* for you. Inputs are separated from whitespaces.

So writing

```
std::string str_1, str_2, str_3, str_4, str_5;
std::cin >> str_1 >> str_2 >> str_3 >> str_4 >> str_5;
```

will do what you want to achieve.

---

If you really need to have the input stored into a single string 1st, you should use the [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function:

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin,str);
```

and use a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to split up the individual values:

```
std::istringstream iss(str);
iss >> str_1 >> str_2 >> str_3 >> str_4 >> str_5;
```

Comment: Hi, if using the third method, is there a way to tell the compiler how long each split string should be?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stringstream>

int main()
{
    std::string MasterString = "Super cali\nfragelistic \n expialadogis\n then more words\n hello world";
    std::stringstream iss(MasterString);

    while(iss.good())
    {
        std::string SingleLine;
        getline(iss,SingleLine,'\n');
        // Process SingleLine here
    }
}
```

something like this.